# PrimeNG dataTable: Using a p-checkbox inside a p-column causes Error

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this Datatable that works fine:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="myObjects" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="size" header="Size"></p-column>
    <p-column field="status" header="Is available ?">
        <ng-template let-col let-obj="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="obj.status" [(ngModel)]="obj.status" />
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Now I would like to **replace** the input type="checkbox" with a **PrimeNG checkbox**:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="myObjects" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="size" header="Size"></p-column>
    <p-column field="status" header="Is available ?">
        <ng-template let-col let-obj="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="obj.status"></p-checkbox>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

This causes the following error (in the browser console). **Why ? What am I missing ?**

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.model.indexOf is not a function
TypeError: this.model.indexOf is not a function
    at Checkbox.isChecked (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:110341:45)
    at Checkbox.writeValue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:110362:29)
```

Full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/VXFpbhx7)

Comment: Here `[(ngModel)]="obj.status"`, obj.status should be of type array. As you are using check box in table, you are actually creating group of check boxes. You should be using it like ` <p-checkbox name="groupname" [value]="obj.status" [(ngModel)]="selectedRows"></p-checkbox>` and in ts file have variable like `selectedRows : []any` read complete detail  here for check box multple mode [https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox)

Comment: Not quite, but in the docs I found this, which works: <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="value" binary="true"></p-checkbox> Thanks. Simply write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please use checkbox with binary option

```
 <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="obj.status" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
```

Comment: This really worked & saved so much of time thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use all attributes of p-checkbox

`<p-checkbox name="checkbox" value="isAC" label="All Colors" [(ngModel)]="selectedAllColors" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="al" binary="true"></p-checkbox>`

and more importantly, don't forget to include `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}` as well.